# Get the URL of a UIWebview after doing [webView goBack]

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I understand that you can get the current URL of a UIWebview via the following code:

```
 NSString *urlString = [[[webView request] URL] absoluteString];
```

However, I've found that this only works for a webView that you have actually loaded.

At some point in my application, I'm doing this: [webView goBack] which will show the webView's previous page.  However, calling the above line to get the URL doesnt reflect the actual page shown.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be a safe approach to get the URL at the moment the page has been fully loaded :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

  NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];
  NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];
  NSLog(@"Current URL is %@", currentURL.absoluteString);

}
```

Does this work for you ?

Comment: this is the answer, a more simplified way would be webView.request.URL.absoluteString. If you need to set a textfield you could do texField.text = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

Comment: Heads up: this method won't fire if goBack takes you to a previous anchor in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the delegate function

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Before every page is about to start loading in your webview (even the goback) will give a call in the above function and the `request` object give the url is going to load.

**Note**: return `YES` if you allow the webview to load the page else `NO`.

Hope this help you solve your problem.

Comment: that sounds like the best option. Although I am not sure if that gets called when simply going back as this may not require any loading.

Comment: it will get called when you call the `goBack` of `UIWebView`. Try it.

Comment: I wasn't sure, thanks for checking back. You had my up vote right away ;). Let's see if kurisukun gets it to work.

Comment: This also worked, but in the context of my project, I went for the solution below.  Thank you very much however!

Comment: -1 This function is not called when the goback is loaded from cache. It is not reliable.